# How do I remove extra spaces in PPT using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can anyone help me with the below code? I am trying to use VBA to remove any extra spaces in a PowerPoint presentation.

```
Sub removeSpaces()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    Do While InStr(shp, "  ") > 0
        shp.Value = Replace(shp, "  ", " ")
        shp.Value = Trim(shp.Value)
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

When I currently run it, it shows an error of "Method or data member not found" and highlights the "shp.Value" part.

Comment: There is no value member variable for Shape.  Are you looking for possibly Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `Shape` object doesn't have a `.Value` property. The `Instr` function may also not evaluate against a `Shape` object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff747227(v=office.14).aspx

Generally, you need to refer to the shape's `TextFrame`, like:

```
Dim shpText as String

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            shpText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Get the shape's text
            Do While InStr(shpText, "  ") > 0
                shpText = Trim(Replace(shpText, "  ", " "))
            Loop
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shpText 'Put the new text in the shape
        Else
            shpText = vbNullString
        End If
    Next shp    
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: when I ran that code, it highlighted "Next shp" and said it is a "Compile Error: Next without For"

Comment: Move the `Next shp` outside of the `If/Else` block.  I will revise the answer above.

Comment: You also ned to add `Loop` statement corresponding with your `Do While`, I didn't notice that in your OP but your code wouldn't compile as it was written here.

Comment: I thought if you used a `For each slide` statement that loops through the whole presentation, so what does the `loop` statement do?

Comment: Each `For` statement needs its own `Next`. The `Loop` statement belongs with the `Do While`: *as long as `shpText` contains the `"  "`, the Loop will operate..

Comment: so now I am getting another error. I went into my draft presentation to input an extra space between two words then ran the code - it popped up with a runtime error and highlighted the `shpText=Replace(shp,"  "," ")` line.

Comment: `shpText = Replace(shpText, "  ", " ")` sorry for the typo, you can't use the `Replace` function on the `shp` object, use it on the `shpText` string. :)