# Removing extra spaces of a text without losing style of slide using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to remove extra spaces in text using trim method and with the help of following: [How do I remove extra spaces in PPT using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34495654/11710036)

The problem is, it is changing font color, styling and setting all text in slide to single format/style.

Example:
Slide has blue colored bold title, remaining text is in black. After running above code the title is changing its style (i.e it is changed to black and not bold).

Comment: Few of them are not solved yet, I thought people can help me if it is open. Sure I will close the rest, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly revised version of the code in the linked question that uses [`TextRange.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.replace) instead of writing the trimmed text back to the shape. It should maintain the formatting.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim shpTextRng As TextRange
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set shpTextRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

                Do While InStr(shpTextRng.Text, "  ") > 0
                    shpTextRng.Replace FindWhat:="  ", ReplaceWhat:=" "
                Loop
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```